# Как выбрать один объект с помощью курсора в Godot?

Tags: godot

У меня есть редактор уровней для 2Д игры в зачаточном состоянии, у меня не получается удалять объекты с помощью него так как когда я нажимаю на ПКМ у _input срабатывает триггер на все объекты что я наставил. Я подозреваю это из-за того что объекты наследуются из одного предка в котором я и прописывал скрипт удаления, но как это исправить чтобы при нажатии мышью срабатывал только один объект? Именно тот на который нажат ПКМ'ом.

[Вот ссылка на сам проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls5v8n6ixfa2zwt/SK2.zip?dl=1)

Например тут! я не могу удалить одного волка который наследуется от Entity.gd, вместо этого срабатывает `func _input(event):` на всех волках и слизнях.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился, я тупо забыл форму объектам указать.

Comment: В таком случае предлагаю отметить данный ответ как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста

Comment: @4500zenja Написано что я через сутки только могу это сделать, спасибо, если не забуду то обязательно отмечу